# From dictionary,append all the values from a dictionary into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate all the values in a dictionary to a list.

```py
a={'alpha':1.2,'beta':0.5}
```

Here I want the output as:

```
[1.2,0.5]
```

```py
ls=[]
for i in a.items():

    for j in i:

        if j==int:

            ls.append(j)
```

Output as

```
[1.2,0.5]
```

Comment: in order to use the value of alpha what should i do?

Comment: `ls = list(a.values())`

Answer (score -1):

Try this ,may help

```
a={'alpha':1.2,'beta':0.5}
ls=[]
for it in a.values():
    ls.append(it)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code, similar to yours

```
ls=[]

for i in a.items():
    ls.append(i[1])
print(ls)
```

best, giulio